# Passing pointer to derived class, to function that expects pointer to base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, polymorphism, virtual

OK. I'm not very good at polymorphism in C++, but I've a problem now. Imagine these classes:

```
class Parent {
public:
     Parent();
     virtual ~Parent();
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
     Child();
};

class Director
public:
     Director();
     void doStuff(Parent* p);
};


// Assume we have a instance of Director, and call the doStuff function here:
doStuff(new Child()); // Gives error
```

I get the error

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Child *' to 'Parent *'

And my simple question is, WHY this doesn't work?
Do I need to do any sort of casting or what, or what is the problem?

**EDIT:**
I put all my files here as they are.
I think the problem lies in my inclusions, since I really dont have any idea of how it's supposed to be done with #ifndef and such. Please check them out. 
Director.h: http://pastebin.com/2uJqezju 
Director.cpp: http://pastebin.com/SZ6cuBJC
IApp.h: http://pastebin.com/euCAwpnL
IApp.cpp: http://pastebin.com/JHDuQUhW
IScene:h: http://pastebin.com/cweH9G6p
IScene.cpp: http://pastebin.com/9epW0dRA

Then I have created some instances of it:
GameApp.h (inherits EDGE::IApp): http://pastebin.com/QbjbVqSi
GameApp.cpp: http://pastebin.com/sYJvmbeP
GameScene.h (inherits EDGE::IScene): http://pastebin.com/K1WYNvRf
GameScene.cpp: http://pastebin.com/uJx3FLBW

Don't be afraid to check them out, there are really like 10 lines of code in each of them. But the problem is in GameApp.cpp where I try to create an instance of GameScene, and pass it to the Director->createNewScene(IScene* scene).

Comment: It [works for me](http://ideone.com/ZXH9rm) when I make a compilable example out of your code fragments. Could you post a complete compilable program that demonstrates the error?

Comment: same here: http://codepad.org/aB6zAyq5

Comment: Should work fine. Do you have something that's interfering with the definition or inheritance of the classes? Maybe your code in reality isn't quite the same as you've posted here.

Comment: Make sure you're deriving from correct class. With namespaces it may happen that you've actually derived from some other class also named `Parent`.

Comment: OK so I now edited the post and attached my source files. Please check them out, there are really not much code at all in them.

Comment: Iscene.h has one `}` too many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Director.h:

```
class IScene;
```

should be inside namespace

Comment: Thank you so much. That was it, nailed it!