# How can I pass pointer-pointers of a derived class as a based class?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, polymorphism

This is a follow-up to [the question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098788/pass-a-pointer-to-a-derived-class-pointer-as-a-parameter-to-a-constructor-expect).

---

### LIB_A

I have this base class in an external library, say, **LIB_A**.

```
class Instrument
{
    // ...
}
```

---

### LIB_B

I have this derived class in another external library, say, **LIB_B**, which of course references **LIB_A**.

```
class Bond : public Instrument
{
    // ...
};
```

In **LIB_B**, I also have a `Trader` class that owns a pointer to the bond it's working with.

```
class Trader
{
public:
    // ...
    Bond* _bond;
};
```

---

### LIB_C

I cannot touch **LIB_A** or **LIB_B**.

In my own code, a *third* "library" (I'm using the term loosely here), say, **LIB_C**, I'm trying to create a class that *points* to a `Trader`'s `Bond` *pointer*, *i.e.*

```
class TradeHelper
{
public:
    TradeHelper(Bond** bondPtr): _bondPtr(bondPtr) {}
    Bond** _bondPtr;
};
```

with it being constructed by

```
Trader* t; // assume this is given and not null
TradeHelper* th = new TradeHelper(&(t->_bond))
```

---

### An Aside (no need to read)

Why such a convoluted scheme? Well, `Trader::_bond` can change, and `TradeHelper` needs to know what that `Trader`'s `_bond` is, at all times. So essentially, `TradeHelper` gets *linked* to a `Trader`. Which is why, if I had the freedom to do things *my* way, I would have done exactly as described—linked the two like this:

```
class TradeHelper
{
public:
    TradeHelper(Trader* t): _trader(t) {}
    Trader* _trader;
};
```

with it being constructed by

```
Trader* t; // assume this is given and not null
TradeHelper* th = new TradeHelper(t);
```

and simply referred to the `Bond` via `_trader->_bond`.

Alas, for reasons of history and just-the-way-things-are, the only thing I have available to me for constructing `TradeHelper` is a pointer to `Trader::_bond`, not the `Trader` itself. Hence my use of the double-pointer.

---

### The Problem

Well, everything, as described, would work fine. But the real problem is that **LIB_C** cannot reference **LIB_B**, only **LIB_A**. What that means is that `TradeHelper` cannot know about `Bond`, only `Instrument`. My example rewritten, now looks like this:

```
class TradeHelper
{
public:
    TradeHelper(Instrument** instPtr): _instPtr(instPtr) {}
    Instrument** _instPtr;
};
```

And therein lies the problem, when I construct it:

```
TradeHelper* th = new TradeHelper(&(t->_bond));
```

As I learned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098788/pass-a-pointer-to-a-derived-class-pointer-as-a-parameter-to-a-constructor-expect), there is no implicit conversion from `Bond**` to `Instrument**`.

I guess the abstract question is very similar to the one I asked previously: **How can I pass a pointer-to-a-derived-class-pointer as a pointer-to-a-base-class-pointer, given that I am allowed to assume that the pointers would be used safely?** In the previous question I sought what I was doing *wrong*, and having learned, I felt I needed to describe my situation in more detail for anyone to be able to suggest a way forward.

Reworded, I want object X to always know "where" another object Y's member is, but that member is a derived class, and object X only knows about the base class.

I've tinkered with pointer references and casting but can't seem to figure a way out.

Comment: Why can't you reference lib b?

Comment: Is the problem that LIB_C may not include / refer to the compiled LIB_B or really you cannot *just* include the header where `Bond` is declared / forward-declare `Bond` yourself in LIB_C?

Answer (score 0):

I've reconstructed your example using dynamic_cast and I had no problems constructing TradeHelper this way. Is there a reason you can't use dynamic_cast in your code?

```
Trader trader;
Bond b;
trader._bond = &b;
Trader* t = &trader;

Instrument* inst = dynamic_cast<Instrument*>(t->_bond);
if (inst == NULL) {
    std::cout << "dynamic_cast failed!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

TradeHelper* th = new TradeHelper(&inst);
delete th;
```

Comment: He can't see the definition of Bond.